# managing state with FRP

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, frp

Some say that FRP is about handling event streams without explicitly managing state. This person, for example:

http://www.slideshare.net/borgesleonardo/functional-reactive-programming-in-clojurescript

Others motivate FRP by pointing out the difficulties of programming entirely by side-effects, as one must do with asynchronous callbacks.

http://cs.brown.edu/~sk/Publications/Papers/Published/mgbcgbk-flapjax/

However in experimenting with FRP (flapjax), I keep hitting the same problem: an inability to handle state, except explicitly, via side-effects.

For example, an animation queue. Changes arrive on an event stream. When the first change arrives, I need to queue a draw to happen some time in the future (e.g. with window.requestAnimationFrame), and arrange to accumulate changes between now and the future draw event. When the draw event happens, I need to draw the accumulated changes.

This is about six lines of code using an imperative style with observer pattern, but I can't find a reasonable way to express this in FRP. The only thing that comes close involves closing the related event streams over a shared state, and explicitly managing the state and rendering events via side-effects. It's hardly an improvement on imperative callbacks.

How is this supposed to be handled in FRP?

Here's a flapjax utility for closing over state:

```
function worldE(init, handlers) {
    var r = fj.receiverE();
    fj.forEach(function(h) {
        h[0].mapE(function (ev) {
            r.sendEvent(init = h[1](init, ev));
        });
    }, handlers);
    return r;
}
```

And here it is used in an animation loop:

```
function initialize(opts) {
    var blitE = fj.receiverE();

    function accumulate(state, data) {
        if (!state.queued) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(blitE.sendEvent);
        }
        return {queued: true, changes: _.extend({}, state.changes, data)};
    }

    function dodraw(state, _) {
        draw(state.changes);
        return {queued: false, changes: {}};
    }

    worldE({queued: false, changes: {}},
            [[opts.data_source, accumulate], [blitE, dodraw]]);
}
```

Things to note: it's larger, less readable and less maintainable than the equivalent callback code. It still requires explicitly managing state. And it operates via side effects.

Is there a better way of doing this in FRP? A different pattern, or a different library?

Comment: I'm not familiar with flajax but you may also try RxJs. It may have a different, better syntax. Also, if you want to see some more complex examples for FRP, take a look at the ELM language http://elm-lang.org/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Flapjax, but looking at the docs, you can use `collectE` to create a stream accumulating the state.
Then, create a second stream of animationFrame events using `receiverE` and `sendEvent`.

Finally, emulate bacon.js's `sampledBy` (https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/wiki/Diagrams#sampledby) to create a third stream of [animationFrame, state] tuples.

Answer (score 0):

Here a bit more flapjax sugar: instead of using sampledBy use snapshotE which will snapshot already collected changes array on each frame event. Check your google groups topic, I've writen some code for it.

Answer (score 0):

FRP is entirely about managing state. But its about managing state without time. To do this you must keep the state within the tree or graph. This prevents any old bit of code from mutating it **at some random point in time**.

In FRP state is only updated when a parent node fires an update. When this happens that events value (and any other parents value) are used to calculate the new nodes value.

blandw's answer above is correct as collectE is what you want.

In collectE the previous value of this node is provided when its parent node fires. This allows you to store any state you wish, such as a collection of changes. But this collection is only ever updated when a parent event has fired.

So by restricting your mutation of state to when the parents update, you save alot of hassel. This is hard to see with a basic example. It becomes more apparent when you have worked on a large project.

However to updates blandw's answer, do not use receiverE for any reason other than getting events out of non frp systems. This should never happen in the middle of an FRP graph, but only as a top level node with no parents.
It use in any other case violates the whole point of FRP.